# Error while converting weekdays from integer to actual name

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, calendar

I'm trying to convert `pd.dt.weekdays()` column from their integer form to its actual name using the calendar library in python.
Here's what I have been doing,

```
hours = uber_data["Date/Time"].dt.hour
week_day = uber_data["Date/Time"].dt.weekday
date = uber_data["Date/Time"].dt.date
weekly_data = pd.concat([week_day, hours, date], axis=1)
weekly_data.columns = ["Week Day", "Hour", "Date"]

weekly_data["Week Day"] = weekly_data["Week Day"].apply(lambda x: calendar.day_name[x])
```

The error i get is,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-e18771afc253> in <module>()
----> 1 weekly_data["Week Day"] = weekly_data["Week Day"].apply(lambda x: calendar.day_name[x])
      2 weekly_data["Week Day"]

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4211             else:
   4212                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4213                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4214 
   4215         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-24-e18771afc253> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 weekly_data["Week Day"] = weekly_data["Week Day"].apply(lambda x: calendar.day_name[x])
      2 weekly_data["Week Day"]

/usr/lib/python3.6/calendar.py in __getitem__(self, i)
     76 
     77     def __getitem__(self, i):
---> 78         funcs = self._days[i]
     79         if isinstance(i, slice):
     80             return [f(self.format) for f in funcs]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I have tried with changing the dtype of the Week Day column but the error still doesnt go.
Edit:
The problem was solved by using `Series.dt.day_name()`. Would appreciate if anyone could provide a solution with the calendar library.

Comment: can you provide the dataset for testing? or try `uber_data["Date/Time"].dt.weekday_name` directly to get the weekday name, if you have dates, you dont need calendar and apply here, pandas has a builtin: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday_name.html

Comment: It did the job thanks....[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/fivethirtyeight/uber-pickups-in-new-york-city) is the link to the dataset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Series.dt.day_name`:

```
weekly_data = pd.DataFrame()
weekly_data['Week Day'] = uber_data["Date/Time"].dt.hour
weekly_data['Hour'] = uber_data["Date/Time"].dt.weekday
weekly_data['Date'] = uber_data["Date/Time"].dt.date
weekly_data['Day'] = uber_data["Date/Time"].dt.day_name()
print(weekly_date)
```